# Prevent Apache logging. SetEnvIf dontlog not working

Tags: apache

I want to prevent certain URLs from being logged to my Apache log. I have tried adding

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI  "/page1/" dontlog
```

in httpd.conf, but /page1/ URLs are still being logged. I have, of course, restarted Apache.

Is there something else that I need to set?

Answer (score 0):

In one case, I had an issue where every which way I went with a particular `SetEnvIf` condition it was still being logged.

I ended up moving that particular `SetEnvIf` condition outside and above my `VirtualHost` declaration and finally my condition stopped being logged.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/my_URI/" dontlog
<VirtualHost :*.80>
....
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined env=!dontlog
</VirtualHost>
```